# Powershell query - Add email ids from SharePoint group into an email

Tags: powershell

I have few email ids generated using the below script:

**Script 1:**

```
Get-SPSite https://SitecollectionURL |
Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb |
Select -ExpandProperty Groups |
Where {$_.Name -EQ "SP Group Name"} |
Select -ExpandProperty Users |
Select Email
```

I have the below Powershell script to send email to users:

**Script 2:**

```
$smtp = "SMTP server addresss" 
$to = "usersfromgroup@company.com"  
$from = "sharepoint@company.com" 
$subject = "This is a Test of HTML Email"   
$body = "Dear Users"  
$body += "We are testing HTML email"  
$body += "<html> Click <a href=http://www.google.com>here</a>  to open google</html>"  
send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

How can i use the email ids generated by the 1st script into the second script($to) to send an email to all the users in the group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use piping to iterate through all results

e.g.

```
param(
    $webUrl = "http://yoursite",
    $groupTitle = "your group"
)

clear-host

function Send-Mail($to){

    write-host "Sending email to $to..."
    $smtp = "SMTP server addresss"
    $from = "sharepoint@company.com" 
    $subject = "This is a Test of HTML Email"   
    $body = "Dear Users"  
    $body += "We are testing HTML email"  
    $body += "<html> Click <a href=http://www.google.com>here</a>  to open google</html>"  
    send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtp -To $to -From $from -Subject $subject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml

}

Get-SPSite $webUrl | Select -ExpandProperty RootWeb | 
    Select -ExpandProperty Groups | 
    Where {$_.Name -eq $groupTitle} | 
    Select -ExpandProperty Users | 
    Select * | %{ 

        #do stuff here
        if($_.Email)
        {           
            Send-Mail $_.Email          
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick resposne. So should I use $_.Email in $to? like $to = "$_.Email"?

Comment: that's right. you can also create a helper function to send emails and receive $_.Email as the $to parameter, assuming all other parameters are static

Comment: I receive the below error when i do this:                                                                           Send-MailMessage : The specified string is not in the form required for an e-ma
il address.                                                                                                                       Send-MailMessage : A recipient must be specified.

Comment: maybe some of your user objects don't have an email. you have to sanitize the value.

Comment: the email ids are displayed(as sending email to email1,sending email to email2) but they were not included into the email and email was not fired.

Comment: you'll have to update the question with the current script, otherwise it's hard to say. you can try adding .ToString()

Comment: script updated as per your code